# SOT23 (SOT23-3) component identification - top marking BKML1

Tags: identification, components

I am trying to identify the SOT23 in the picture BKML1. It is connected to the Isense pin of a UC3843B current-mode PWM controller J31, already removed. The PCB is a control board for an Outback Inverter. The circuit is part of the board's power supply DC-DC.

I have applied power to the board downstream from this circuit and the microcontrollers seem to still be alive; some LED flashing occurs. The MOSFET driving the transformer failed a DMM test, so I suspect that if I replace all the components in this part of the circuit it should work again.

[image]

Comment: Based on J31's datasheet, it may be an NPN transistor. Can you trace components around it and provide a shcematic?

Comment: Q parts are typically PNP, NPN or JFET.

Comment: @tobalt Or MOSFETs, more likely. I see a lot more MOSFETs than BJTs these days. And JFETs are rare.